# How can I customize the test part of my multi output model in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, tf.keras

I'm building a multi output model, in inference/test part I need to 'exit' (don't continue with the computation of the next layers) and pass to the next input when I receive a good confidence from the first output. The train part is done using simply model.compile() and model.fit(). In some sense I have to customize only the test part.

I would like to avoid writing the train part by hand

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "test part"?

Comment: When I apply the model on new data in order to take the predictions